# Not able to check and uncheck checkbox on edit action through fetching data from database

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Not able to check and uncheck checkbox on edit action through fetching data from database

my ajax code

```
success: function(data)
                                        {

                                        $('[name="e_id"]').val(data.e_id);
                                        $('[name="s_id"]').val(data.s_id);
                                        $('[name="e_title"]').val(data.e_title);
                                        $('[name="e_description"]').val(data.e_description);
                                        $('[name="org_id"]').val(data.org_id);


                                       $('[name="enable_reg"]').prop('checked');

                                        $('[name="enable_payment"]').val(data.enable_payment);
                                        $('[name="enable_photo"]').val(data.enable_photo);
                                        $('[name="is_clg"]').val(data.is_clg);
                                        $('[name="e_branch"]').val(data.e_branch);
                                        $('[name="e_path"]').val(data.e_path);
                                        $('[name="e_type"]').val(data.e_type);
                                        $('[name="e_sub_type"]').val(data.e_sub_type);
                                        $('[name="e_no_player"]').val(data.e_no_player);
                                        $('[name="e_no_sub"]').val(data.e_no_sub);
                                        $('[name="e_last_date"]').val(data.e_last_date);
                                        $('[name="e_timestamp"]').val(data.e_timestamp);


                                        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
```

my html code bootstrap modal

```
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label for="enable_reg">Registration</label>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="enable_reg" id="enable_reg">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the property correctly.

Something like:

```
$('[name="enable_reg"]').prop('checked', data.checked);
```

will do, assuming that `data.checked` is either true or false.

see jQuery [docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/)